# SSRS Interactive Sorting child group from parent

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, columnsorting

Here's the issue.

I have the following report, which consists of a table (not matrix) that has 3 different levels of grouping

[`Report Design`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD5Zq.png)

I'm quite familiar with a basic function of interactive sorting, but what i need to do here is as follows:

Having in mind the pic previously shown, I need to add a Interactive sorting to the column "Porcentaje %" (percentage)  in each one of the repetitions of LV1 entries, the issue is that I need that the sorting works on the LV3 group WITHOU affecting the sorting of LV2 group.

I have made the basic configurations on the **Textbox Properties** dialog, in the **Interactive Sorting** section, and the report do not crash, but also doesnt sort the information.

any ideas on how to do this?

Also, the headers are part of a ColumnGroup that repeats on each month i'm filtering on the report. Said group has the property Hidden set as true, and is toggled by a "Totals" columns outside the group.

Comment: The closest I can come up with would be to expose a field representative of LVL2 and then sort 1st LVL2 and 2nd LVL3. I know this is not the desired output, however, I don't think you can sort outside of the outer group.

Comment: What about chosing a sort button in LV2?

Comment: Sadly because management orders

Comment: @WolfgangKais extending my last answer: As you can see in the report desing image, there are cases when **Porcentaje %** value is the same for all the LV3 members (refer to teh line where it says **Contratos por traspasos** so management people told me that it would be meaningless to have a sort button in LV2

Comment: Well, for me the meaning of a sort button in level 1 would be to sort level 2. I think the "meaning" will come to the management peaple once the button is placed in the level-2-row. An maybe that's also the way to tell SSRS the meaning that you have in mind. And tell the management people that If all percentage values in level 3 are the same, then it will be meaningless to click a button to sort them, no matter where that button is placed. :)